# Timeout while trying to contact RemoteTestNG in Selenium on Mac

Tags: selenium, testng, osx-mountain-lion, ubuntu-12.04

I have a TestNG setup running on Eclipse Indigo 20120216-1857 and TestNG for Eclipse v2.0.  Dev environment is Mac OSX 10.8.2.  Target is a web server running on Ubuntu 12.04.

Error: 'Couldn't contact the RemoteTestNG client.  Make sure you don't have an older version of testng.jar on your class path.'

This error only happens when i'm running selenium scripts.  not on my other api oriented test cases.  I have selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar running.

This same setup is working on my windows 7 dev environment.

This is a brand new eclipse setup and workspace on the mac.

Comment: what version of testng plugin do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I had met same question. I hope my resolved method can help you.

Method:
Please open Eclipse->Preferences->Then click TestNG->Restore Defaults

root reason: I had use ReportNG instead of testng default report,but after that I forgot to restore config. So when I make a new project,run as TestNG,but not add ReportNG jars, it report error.