# "Couldn't connect to the RemoteTestNG Client" at launch of TestNG on OSX-mountain-lion

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, osx-mountain-lion, testng

I am attempting to run the most basic example test using Eclipse, Selenium, Maven, and TestNG. I can run a test with Eclipse (or IntelliJ), Selenium, and Maven, (jUnit also works) but when I try to add in TestNG, I get the following:

"Couldn't connect to RemoteTestNG client. Make sure you don't have an older version of testng.jar on your class path. Reason: Timeout while trying to contact RemoteTestNG."

I have followed several tutorials and youtube walkthroughs. I performed the same steps on a Windows 7 VM and it worked the first time, so I think I am doing the configuration properly (i.e. classpaths).

I saw there were other similar topics:
[Timeout while trying to contact RemoteTestNG in Selenium on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739996/timeout-while-trying-to-contact-remotetestng-in-selenium-on-mac)
["Couldn't contact the RemoteTestNG client" error when trying to run tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440099/couldnt-contact-the-remotetestng-client-error-when-trying-to-run-tests)

but they were old and didn't seem to answer my question specifically.

I have never used these tools before, nor am I very familiar with Macs, so I have, as of yet, not been able to try running the same thing from the command line as I don't know exactly what command to use.

Is there a certain something I am missing or need to do for TestNG to work? Otherwise, I will have to always use the Windows VM which would be a pain.

**Environment:** 
OS: OS X 10.8.5
TestNG: 6.8
Eclipse IDE for Java: Kepler SR1
Selenium: 2.38.0
Java: 1.7.0_45

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

1. Navigte to:

   ```
   Project -> properties ->TestNG
   ```
2. Unselect the option:

   ```
   Use Project TestNg jar.
   ```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message.

OS: Linux Mint 15 Olivia
TestNG: 6.8.7
Eclipse IDE for Java: Kepler
Java: 1.6

I fixed the problem doing this :

Open the "Run configuration" (Run > Run Configuration) window of eclipse. Delete all the tests under "TestNG" (there were deleted tests).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The issue is that I had placed .jars in the Java/Extensions folder (including testng6.8.jar). Apparently this caused a conflict with maven. Cleaned it out and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Navigte to:

Project -> properties ->TestNG
Unselect the option:

Use Project TestNg jar.
This solved my issue.

Share
Edit
Following

this resolved my issue